# NodeJS error on String method match

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

I've been trying it for hours and cannot find out the reason why its happening.

I'm simply calling `match` method on a string and this is what I'm getting:

`TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined`

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
function validateURL (url) {
    return url.match( '((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s"]*))' );
}
```

I also tried using `toString()` but get the same error like:

`TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined`

I'm not sure why its happening. Also checked `typeof` for `url` and got `string`.

Comment: Are you sure the typeof is still `string`? Put a `console.log(typeof(url))` before the return and try again.

Comment: @aurbano Yes, I'm sure as I already mentioned I've debugging it for hours now. Also tried your code, `string` given.

Comment: It's either undefined, or it's not the code you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, adding `"" +` made it work.

```
function validateURL (url) {
    return "" + url.match( '((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s"]*))' );
}
```